# Should I annotate pojo class with @Component?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

I searched whether I should annotate POJO with @Component or not. It seems like it is recommended not to annotate pojo.

Here is my **OrderStatusMnemonic** Configuration class that reads a txt file:

```
@Configuration
public class OrderStatusMnemonic {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("OrderStatusMnemonic.class");
    
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    
    @Autowired
    public OrderStatus orderStatus;

    public OrderStatusMnemonic(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            log.info("Loading order-status-mnemonic file ");
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:order-status-mnemonic.txt");
            InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            
            String str;
            List<String> orderStatusMnemonicList = new ArrayList<>();
            while ( (str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.info("str = " + str);
                            
                orderStatusMnemonicList.add(str);
            }
            
            orderStatus.setValues(orderStatusMnemonicList);
            
            log.info("orderStatusMnemonicList = " + orderStatusMnemonicList.toString());
            
            
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            log.error("Failing to Load order status mnemonic file" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
        
}
```

**OrderStatus** POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class OrderStatus {
    private List<String> values;
}
```

Since I am autowiring OrderStatus POJO class I am getting error:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.spectrum.sci.osm.orderstatus.OrderStatus' in your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OrderStatus` as it is now does not need annotation `@Component` so you should not add it. Also you should not try to `@Autowire` it anywhere without `@Component`.

You surely can add `@Component` and then `@Autowire` it anywhere you need it but there is no point in it since you can more easy instantiate your POJO by just issuing `new OrderStatus()`. And it might also be a waste of resources.

Then, when do you need those two annotations? Whenever your POJO needs to become a managed bean. In other words when there is a need for Spring to do some automagical things. Consider your POJO would have something more complex, like (check the comments):

```
// Enables autowiring OrderStatus -> autowired OrderStatus is managed 
// by Spring
@Component 
public class OrderStatus {
    private List<String> values;
    // Then there is something to autowire to OrderStatus also
    // Without OrderStatus being managed by Spring this would be ignored!
    // But because managed, Spring autowires also this one
    // Of course SomeOtherManagedBean must be a @Component, for example
    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherManagedBean somb;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Component or @Autowired should be used only for classes managed by Spring. POJOs are not managed by Spring. So, should neither add @component nor you should autowire it. Since you are trying to autowire POJO class, you are getting error to define bean of type OrderStatus

Answer (score 0):

Any `plain-vanilla Java Class` which is being used as `light weight bean` and treated/called as **POJO** should not be bound with any of the Spring components.

The java class can be decorated with either of the spring annotations (i.e. `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Bean`, `@Configuration`) only if that class has been enhanced by `adding extra flavour` and only if that class is being used to support other classes with enhanced features other then getter setter properties.

`@Autowired` can be used only if the class is marked with any of the spring components as the `@Autowired` is spring annotation which would scan only those beans which are being managed withing Spring.